# MySQL procedure that accepts multiple parameters.

Tags: mysql

I want to write a MySQL optimized query with multiple parameters. A parameter may be `null`. If it is `null` the procedure should return all rows. Otherwise it should only return the specific rows. This is what I have so far:

```
where
wsj.`IsVerified`=1
and
 if (FindWhere != NULL)
 then 
 begin
    wsj.`ExpectedLocation` like
         Concat('%',ifnull(FindWhere,wsj.`ExpectedLocation`),'%')
    or wsj.`CurrentLocation` like
         Concat('%',ifnull(FindWhere,wsj.`CurrentLocation`),'%')
    or  wsl.`City` like 
         Concat('%',ifnull(FindWhere,wsl.`City`),'%') 
    or wsl.`State` like 
         Concat('%',ifnull(FindWhere,wsl.`State`),'%')
    or  wsl.`Country` like 
         Concat('%',ifnull(FindWhere,wsl.`Country`),'%')
 end
 END IF;
```

Comment: Use `FindWhere IS NOT NULL` instead of `!= NULL`

Comment: It would be nice to also provide the schema of the database or table(s) you are interested in.